# Check for basic concepts

Tags: real-analysis

1) $B = (0,1) \cup \{2\}$ , the derived set of $B$ which contains all limit points in $B$ is $[0,1]$, right?

2) $B = (0,1) \cap Q$, the closure of $B$ is $[0,1]$ too right?

3) a subset of $\Bbb R$ whose only limit point is $1$... Will $\{1+ 1/n: n\in\Bbb N\}$ work?

4) 
an interval on which the function $f(x) = \frac 1{1-x^2}$ is uniformly continuous

$R \setminus \{1\}$ work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1) Yes. Also, the closure is $[0,1]\cup \{2\}$.

2) Yes.

3) Yes.

4) I'm too lazy to check, but just take $[100, 101]$. Any continuous function on a closed interval is uniformly continuous.

Comment: For 4 how do you check?

Comment: Also, 1/(1-x^2) is not continuous at 1 though

Comment: @afsdfdfsaf It's continuous on the interval $[100,101]$, which is all that matters.

Comment: @afsdfdfsaf Your given interval won't work because it contains $-1$, and the function isn't defined there.

Comment: Any closed interval does not involve 1 will work right by the way this is uniformly continuous

Comment: @afsdfdfsaf Yes. This is a standard theorem that should be in your textbook.